How to omit 3 levels inner key in typescript?
Giving following typescript code. how would you omit the email that is inside options and inside data?
interface SignUpObject {
  email:string, // not this one
  password: string,
  options: {
    emailRedirectTo: string,
    captchaToken?: string,
    data: {
      preferedLanguage: number
      name: string
      email: string // but this one!
      agreeTermsCheckbox: boolean
      whatJobYouHave: number
      birthday: string
      techYearsOfExpierence: string
      is_subscriber: boolean
      is_admin: boolean
      subscriber_expiration_timestamp: string | null
    }
  }
}

I already omit password:
interface UpdateUserData extends Omit<SignUpObject, 'password'> {
  password?: string
}

I try search online, reading the docs, looking in forums and more

How generalizable do you want this to be? Are you looking for a utility type that does this in general? Something like NestedOmit<SignUpObject, 'options.data.email'> as shown in this playground link? Or something like OmitAtDepth<SignUpObject, "email", 3> as shown in this playground link? Or are you trying to just do this particular thing in which case the existing answer below suffices? Please [edit] to clarify, and let me know if you want to see any of my suggestions above written as an answer.

Overwrite options.data as you did for password field:
interface UpdateUserData extends Omit<SignUpObject, 'password' | 'options'> {
  password?: string;
  options: Omit<SignUpObject['options'], 'data'>
  & {
    data: Omit<SignUpObject['options']['data'], 'email'>
  }
}


You could use a recursive generic type to filter a particular object path out:
type Leaves<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]:
    `${Exclude<K, symbol>}${Leaves<T[K]> extends never ? "" : `.${Leaves<T[K]>}`}`
}[keyof T] : never

type OmitPath<T, K extends Leaves<T>> = {
  [P in keyof T as P extends K ? never : P]: 
    OmitPath<T[P], K extends `${Exclude<P, symbol>}.${infer R extends Leaves<T[P]>}` ? R : never>
};

type SignUp = OmitPath<SignUpObject, 'options.data.email' | 'options.captchaToken'>

const s: SignUp = {options:{emailRedirectTo: 'test', captchaToken: 'sdf'}}; // captchaToken errored
const s2: SignUp = {options:{emailRedirectTo: 'test', data:{email: 'email'}}}; // email errored

type SignUp = OmitPath<SignUpObject, 'options.data.email' | 'options.captchaToken2'> // options.captchaToken2 errored

Playground
